# How to use offset for dropdowns

Tags: excel

If you have a large set of data how do you eliminate spaces when you have a dropdown in Excel if you have data on row 1 then nothing then data on row 30. etc?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go make another tab filter in the data validation data in that tab then you will need to create a dropdown in that tab then open up name manager and enter this formula in:
=OFFSET(Calc!$E$7,0,0,COUNTA(Calc!$E$7:$E$200),1)